# php read in csv file as array -> file not found

Tags: php, symfony, csv

I am trying to read in a 'csv' file into an array. This picture illustrates the project structure:

[image]

I am trying to read in the 'Terms-to-Block.csv' file withing the 'TagBlacklistValidator' class:

```
public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
{
    $tags = explode(",", $value);

    $blacklist = array_map('str_getcsv', file('../Utilities/Terms-to-Block.csv'));
    var_dump($blacklist);

}
```

I am getting the error 'failed to open stream: No such file or directory'. How do I need to pass the path to 'file(...)' ?
(This annotation is used in 'Entity/Tag.php')

Comment: Instead of `"../"`, what happens if you use `__DIR__."/Utilities/[...]"`?

Comment: "__DIR__" would try to search in "/Constraints/Utilities/Terms-to-Block.csv", i wanted the file to be placed in "/Utilities/" only, not in "/Constraints/Utilities".

Comment: Oh, dangit. I meant `__DIR__."/../Utilities/[...]"`

Comment: Ah, nice. Thank you, didn't know that i could add another "../" after '__DIR__' :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tell PHP to magically insert the directory of the current file before the relative filepath. So:

```
$filename = __DIR__`.'/../Utilities/Terms-to-Block.csv;
```

Comment: Hi, thats what Sverri already commented above, but thanks nevertheless

Comment: @nova.cp It helps if answers hidden in comments are made first-class answers, so that's what I did here, but marked it as community wiki. PS would also be great if you accepted the answer. ;)